# mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

> SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

I get this error message when i use mail() function in php script file...

I m using gmail SMTP server and gmail using STARTTLS which is secure SSL to prevent spams and i already use these commands in my contact.php file

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");
$headers = "";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: garima@gmxxxxail.in";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: <garima@gmxxxxail.in>\r\n";
$email = "gariXXXXXXX12@gmail.com";
$subject = "pagalpanti";
$message = "hi i am here";
$res= mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I've only ever seen [PHPMailer examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) doing this. Doing it with the normal mail() function will be exceedingly difficult.

Comment: TLS doesn't prevent spam... it is only an encrypted transmission channel, like HTTPS. I'd assume you connect to the wrong port (25 is usually for regular SMTP)

Comment: It's working through PHPMailer.